# How to determine the height of hidden/overflowing contents inside a `flex-grow:1` container

Tags: jquery, css

I have a container set with `overflow:hidden` & `flex-grow:1`. When the contents overflow, how do I determine their height with jQuery? I need this value to create a custom scrollbar.

Example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body").height() + "</p>");
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body").innerHeight() + "</p>");
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body").outerHeight() + "</p>");
  
  //hack
  $("div.body").css("overflow", "visible");
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body").height() + "</p>");
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body").innerHeight() + "</p>");
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body").outerHeight() + "</p>");
  $("div.body").css("overflow", "hidden");
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  outline:1px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

div.body {
  overflow:hidden;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="head">head</div>
  <div class="body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget ultrices elit. Mauris in ornare erat. Vivamus interdum turpis nec ipsum eleifend, eu sollicitudin purus porta. Vivamus in malesuada nisi. Donec rutrum urna ipsum, quis euismod dolor venenatis in.</div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```

The only hack I found is to set the element's `overflow` to `visible`, get metrics, and set it back to `hidden` immediately.

Comment: Loop over the children, and sum up their individual heights ...?

Comment: @CBroe it doesn't work with a textNode in this example (`.children()` is empty).

Comment: Well then wrap the content into an additional element first.

Comment: @CBroe the wrapper gets clamped to the parent's dimensions and only the text overflows, that's the issue :-(

Comment: Can't reproduce, works perfectly fine when I try it directly with your given example.

Comment: @CBroe I had en extra `display:flex` on my `div.body` that was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the content into an additional container element, and then simply measure the height of that.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("body").append("<p>" + $("div.body > div").height() + "</p>");
});
```

```css
div.box {
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  outline:1px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

div.body {
  overflow:hidden;
  flex-grow:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="head">head</div>
  <div class="body"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin eget ultrices elit. Mauris in ornare erat. Vivamus interdum turpis nec ipsum eleifend, eu sollicitudin purus porta. Vivamus in malesuada nisi. Donec rutrum urna ipsum, quis euismod dolor venenatis in.</div></div>
  <div class="footer">footer</div>
</div>
```